# how to implementing the Azure Maps API on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, azure-maps

how to use the Azure Maps API with flutter.
I read the Android SDK document, but I have no idea to use on flutter.

Answer (score 1):

In Syncfusion Flutter Maps, you can visualize the Azure maps and customize it easily. To add Azure Maps, you need to add a MapTileLayer to the list of layers in SfMaps. In the MapTileLayer.urlTemplate property, the URL of the provider must be set.

To request tiles from the Azure, you need an API key. Replace the word 'Your-Key' with the actual api-key in the code snippet below.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return SfMaps(
              layers: [
                      MapTileLayer(urlTemplate: 'https://atlas.microsoft.com/map/imagery/png?subscription-key=Your-Key&api-version=1.0&style=satellite&zoom={z}&x={x}&y={y} '),
              ],
      );
}
```